# Apache POI: Cell in Row is null when content was removed in Microsoft Excel

Tags: java, excel, nullpointerexception, apache-poi, xlsx

I am reading an Excel spreadsheet (XLSX) file with Apache POI and I noticed when I open the file in Excel directly and remove the entire content of one row by emptying the cells, save the file, and close the file, the cells of the row from which I removed content from are `null` on code level.

**Note**: a cell is also `null` when it was never filled with any content

In the code, I do the following with Apache POI:

1. Read `workbook` from file
2. Read `sheet` from `workbook`
3. Iterate over `row`s of `sheet`
4. Iterate over `cell`s of `row`
5. Check if `cell == null`

**My method**

```
if (sheet == null) {
    log.error("Sheet is null!");
    return false;
}

//TODO: when content is deleted from excel instead of deleting entire rows, the cells in those rows are 'null'
var valid = true;
for (Row row : sheet) {
    // rowNum starts at 1 if header row was removed
    int rowNum = row.getRowNum();

    for (var i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
        final var cell = row.getCell(i);
        if (cell == null) {
            log.error("Cell {}{} is null or empty!",  Character.toString('A' + i), rowNum + 1);
            valid = false;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

**Apache POI JavaDoc of method Row.getCell(int cellNum)**

```
/**
 * Get the cell representing a given column (logical cell) 0-based.  If you
 * ask for a cell that is not defined....you get a null.
 *
 * @param cellnum  0 based column number
 * @return Cell representing that column or null if undefined.
 * @see #getCell(int, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.MissingCellPolicy)
 */
Cell getCell(int cellnum);
```

In the beginning, I thought that only cells that never had any content before are `null` ("undefined") but it seems that even cells that had content before are null.

**My issue here** is, I cannot differentiated between the case that a cell just was not filled correctly (cell never had any content) and the case that content was intentionally removed (cell did have content before) from the Excel.
A cell that is `null` suggests to a user the latter: some cell was not filled in the Excel; but a cell that is `null` with a cell address where no content is supposed to be, because the content was removed, is confusing to my opinion.

**Workaround**: instead of removing the entire content from a row, you can delete the row all together. But getting all users to do that is unrealistic. The natural thing is to remove the content, not delete the row.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Check for a null cell or a cell of type blank?

Comment: `Row.getCell` returns `null` if the cell does not exists in the row. That means for Office Open XML (`*.xlsx`) there is no `c` element for this cell as child in `row` element. Files in `*.xlsx` format are simple `ZIP` archives. So you can unzip the `*.xlsx` file to see this. You will find something like `...<row r ="3"...><c r="A3"...><c r="C3"...>...</row>...` - there is no `B3`. One has no chance to determine **why** that cell does not exists nor whether it had existed before.

Comment: @AxelRichter: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I had the idea to verify if the number of cells in a row are equal to the value of `numColumns`. So I called `row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells()` but it returns `2` although the entire row is empty.

Comment: Then there are two empty cells in the row. But for those cells `Row.getCell` should not return `null`, except [Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.MissingCellPolicy.html#RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL) is used. But nothing in your provided code shows this.

Comment: @AxelRichter: I do not understand how there could be two cells in the row when I used the same way to remove the content which in other cases would lead to `(cell == null) == true`

Comment: I also do not know why `Excel` sometimes decides to totally remove cells  but sometimes decides to only emptying the cells. I doubt someone except the `Microsoft` programmers will know this. I doubt it is documented somewhere.